# Replace Values Within(not the whole cell) Every Cell in Each Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, text, replace

I want to :
Replace Searched txt in Every Cell in Each Worksheet Using Worksheet index(adding it to "replacetxt" .

this is the code i tried .

But :code runs but nothing happens

```
Sub searchandrep()
Dim WS_Count As integer
Dim i As integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


For i = 2 To WS_Count


activeworkbook.Worksheets(i).rows(1).Replace _ 
 What:="toreplacetext", Replacement:="replacetxt"+cstr(i), _ 
 SearchOrder:=xlByrows, MatchCase:=True


next i

end sub
```

Does anyone of you knows what's the problem in here, or have an alternative solution for this ?

Comment: if this is a one-off, have you considered the edit : find/replace function?

Comment: What is the problem? Error message? And do you really mean every cell? Every populated cell? Only cells in one row?

Comment: i target cells(1,1) in every worksheet there's already just one cell in 1st row , and the problem is code runs but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, although I am not entirely sure of your issue yet! Be sure, if you have no action it is set up correctly to start with.
From your worksheet -> alt-f11 to open vba. Then ->insert -> Module. And paste the code in there.

```
Sub searchandrep()
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To WS_Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Rows(1).Replace _
        What:="a", Replacement:="b" & Str(i), MatchCase:=True
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I was wrong i haven't figured it cause am begineer with vba ,this works fine       ,but what i was trying to do is to search a portion of text within the target cells not the whole cell .I'll try to find it later . Anyways Thanks for your participation and help .

Comment: And If you know a solution of what i'm trying to do , i will be gratefull

Comment: This does search a portion of the cell. aba in cell (A1) in worksheet 2 becomes b 2 bb 2. What were you getting?

Comment: It haven't worked because cells contain a lot of data ;about 14000 lines of text              i think this method doesn't work with voluminous data ,but anyways i've foud a way to accomplish what i want using this one ,   thanks a lot for your help .